# Disk won't go out of readonly

Tags: usb, format

I have this usb that is set to write protected. I need to get it formtatted however everything I tried from

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd1
```

to

```
fdisk /dev/sdd
d
w
```

all end up telling me that I don't have permission to write to this disk. gparted and all the other tools I've tried return the same thing.

```
hdparm -r0 /dev/sdd
```

goes through but then none of the other steps work.

Comment: Funny that you ask that now.  I just threw 2 USB flash drives with the same issue.  I tried everything that I could find under Linux, and Windows, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a disk as read-write isn't necessary to format the disk. Unmount it, if mounted, with:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdd1
```

Then you should be able to delete the partition with GParted and create a new one.

Make sure you are using `sudo` in front of the commands you mentioned.

Comment: Nope. Unmounted and attempted that and there was no result.

Comment: What happened though?